# How can I track and send custom events with the new Google Analytics 4 (gtag.js)?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have an old website that's using the old Google Analytics code from last decade, and I need help using the new GA4.

#### Old Code (2016)

To send custom events and pageviews to Google, I would use the global `ga()` function from their `<script>` snippet:

```js
// Event
ga('send', 'event', {
    eventAction: 'click',
    eventCategory: 'social',
    eventLabel: 'twitter'
});

// Pageview
ga('send', {
    hitType: 'pageview',
    page: 'Video page',
    title: 'Intro video'
});
```

#### New Code (2022)

Google Analytics says that all old properties will stop working on July 1, 2023, so we need to switch to the new Google Analytics 4 property, the `<script>` snippet in the header has changed a bit, now it creates `gtag()`:

```html
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=X-XXX123456"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'X-XXX123456');
</script>
```

But upon trying to use `gtag("send")` like I used to, it looks like nothing gets transmitted to Google anymore. I've tried looking it up, but all tutorials/articles still demonstrate the old approach. How can I send custom events using the new GA4?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Instead of using `"send"`, the recommended name is `"event"` [official docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/events). Also, the recommended parameters should use an underscore, like `event_category`:

```js
// Send custom event
gtag("event", "click", {
    "event_category": "social",
    "event_label": "twitter"
});

// Pageview event
gtag('event', 'page_view', {
    "page_title": "landing-page",
});
```

If you're manually sending custom pageviews, make sure you disable the initial pageview upon landing to avoid counting it twice, as explained in [the "Manual Pageviews" section](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/views?hl=en&client_type=gtag#manual_pageviews) by adding `send_page_view: false` to your initial config call in the header `<script>`:

```
gtag('config', 'TAG_ID', {
    send_page_view: false
});
```

You can check that something is being sent locally by opening your Network Tab and looking at the payload of each `collect` network request:

[image]

Sources:

- [Events documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/events)
- [Pageviews documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/views)

Comment: This seem to work fine, but how do you see the event_category and event_label in GA4? It seems that only the action name is visible everywhere.

Answer (score 7):

This is the syntax to send an event with GA4:

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events) you can see the documentation for the events.

Alternatively, if you want to test the hits and if the events are being sent with which data, you can use the [Google Tag Assistant](https://tagassistant.google.com/) to review that.

Comment: Should this work because the event_label, i.e, a encoded URL is (Not Set) in GA. I want to see URL's in the is report:

gtag('config', 'UA-123456789-1');
                            gtag('event', 'Page Load', {
                    'event_category': 'JavaScript Widgets',
                    'event_label': 'https://www.testdomain.com/test-iframe',
                    'value': 1
                });

Comment: my gtag.js is loaded in iframe but doesn't call `https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect` after, while it calls that collection point normally in regular webpages

Comment: This seem to work fine, but how do you see the event_category and event_label in GA4? It seems that only the action name is visible everywhere.